# flutter permission_handler Build fail

Tags: flutter, permissions, flutter-packages

I am trying to add the package permission_handler to my flutter project but I cannot run the app. I get a build error. This is the error I get

```
C:\Users\Hp\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:321: error: cannot find symbol
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\Hp\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
  location: class permission
C:\Users\Hp\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
  location: class permission
C:\Users\Hp\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
  location: class permission
C:\Users\Hp\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:259: error: cannot 
find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
  location: class permission
C:\Users\Hp\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:270: error: cannot 
find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
  location: class permission
C:\Users\Hp\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:281: error: cannot 
find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
  location: class permission
C:\Users\Hp\dev\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.2.5\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:370: error: cannot 
find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && hasPermissionInManifest(context, null, permission )) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 48s
```

I have reverted to an earlier version but I would like to know what is the cause of this error. My compile version is 30

Answer (score 7):

as said in plugin github repository

> These new permissions are supported on Android 12, to resolve this problem make sure to set the compileSdkVersion in your app/build.gradle file to 31.

for more information have a look at [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/685)

Comment: this actually resolved it but i had to  add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` to gradle properties and everyting was fixed